# How to make discord.py bot respond to spoiler text messages?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was attempting to make my discord bot respond to messages even if it is spoiler marked by users. For example if a user were to send ||Hello|| I would still want my bot to respond.

Here is some relevant code

```
@client.listen ("on_message")
async def hello_message (message):
  if message.content.startswith ("Hello there!"):
    await message.channel.send ("Hello! it is nice to see you")
```

I tried doing something like this

```
@client.listen ("on_message")
async def hello_message (message):
  if message.content.startswith ("||Hello there!||"):
    await message.channel.send ("Hello! it is nice to see you")
```

But that does seem to work.

Also note that I put `client.listen` so that the bot could respond to other commands.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello Robot! Is this within a cog? Does your original on_message event work?

Comment: oh yes the original one does work

Comment: Have you tried sending a spoiler message and printing the content of it? How does it look like? Are you sure the `||` are there? Are you sure the capitalization is also correct? You might be sending `||hello there!||` but you're checking for `||Hello there!||`